# android app displaying image on clicking button

Tags: android

Can someone help me with the code for
-if i click on button it should display a full screen image then again if i click on button on 2nd page it should do the same.

i want to know how to connect different pages/activities,when you click a button it should display some image and then again clickin on that page will display another image and so on,
images should be full screen

Comment: **its working fine but the only problem is that am not able to add buttons & text in the page containing  image to connect to another page containing image ,how to do so??**

Answer (score 0):

In your activity after setting content view use this code to start your image activity.

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    ImageActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Now put a ImageSwitcher or Image view and set a touch or click listener to change Images as per your logic.

Comment: *its working fine but the only problem is that am not able to add buttons & text  in the page containing image to connect to another page containing image ,how to do so??**

Comment: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/pat2"
    >
    
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        
        />
    
    
</LinearLayout>' this is my xml layout

Comment: 'package com.example.akku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Pattern extends Activity{
 
    ImageView img;
    
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.pattern);
  ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
  img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pat2);
  
   
  
 }
 

}' this is my java code.now how to add buttons to it

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imageview-example/ @suma put some efforts use google or a reference book

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two activities :  MyActivity1 and My Activity2
In MyActivity1 class,create a button and on Button's click listener call MyActivity2.class using startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity1.this,MyActivity.class))

MyActivity2 class will contain one ImageView that will have its width and height as "fillparent" value in xml.

You can continue this process for as many activities you want.